# Candidate Elimination - Classification of new data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I'm trying to understand [version space learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_space_learning) and the Candidate Elimination algorithm.
Take these training examples with the following attributes:

```
Sky, Temp, Humid, Wind, Water, Forecast, EnjoySport
```

And the corresponding values:

```
<Sunny, Warm, Normal, Strong, Warm, Same,   Yes>
<Sunny, Warm, High,   Strong, Warm, Same,   Yes>
<Rainy, Cold, High,   Strong, Warm, Change, No>
<Sunny, Warm, High,   Strong, Cool, Change, Yes>
```

If I perform candidate elimination I find that `S` (the most specific hypothesis) and `G` (the most general hypothesis) are:

```
S: {<Sunny, Warm, ?, Strong, ?, ?>}
G: {<Sunny, ?, ? ,? ,?, ?>, <?, Warm, ?, ?, ?, ?>}
```

But, what about classification of new data? I mean, what happens if I have a new data point like this one?

```
<Sunny, Warm, Normal, Strong, Cool, Change>
```

What will the algorithm do?  Will it classify the new record as positive or negative?

I searched a lot of it but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_space_learning#The_version_space_algorithm):

> After learning, classification can be performed on unseen examples by testing the hypothesis learned by the algorithm. If the example is consistent with multiple hypotheses, a majority vote rule can be applied.

`<disclaimer>`Without having much experience with this kind of learning`</disclaimer>`, the intent is to learn a region of the possibility space that can be described by the "general" and "specific" boundaries, perhaps with the ability to interpolate between them.

For example, perhaps you would consider `<Sunny, ?, ? ,Strong ,?, ?>` to an included hypothesis, since it is "between" `<Sunny, Warm, ?, Strong, ?, ?>` and `<Sunny, ?, ? ,? ,?, ?>`.

The hypothesis space identified by the boundaries represents the knowledge your model has learned.  Each hypothesis in it (such as `<Sunny, ?, ? ,Strong ,?, ?>`) will either match a new data point or not.  It is then up to you to decide how to interpret the resulting "opinions". Apparently putting it to a "vote" is common.

To summarize:

1. Enumerate all hypothesis between the most specific and most general boundaries.
2. Tally how each hypothesis reacts to the new data point: does it say yes or no?
3. Does the new data point have more "yes" votes or "no" votes? That is what you label the new point as.

Note that while the above algorithm is good for communicating intent, it may be bad for performance.  In particular, it may be possible to consider groups of included hypotheses at a time.  Doing so would reduce the number of iterations needed.